# Spring Data Mongo - Reusing entity class without indexes

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm building a domain model, and annotating classes with Spring Data Mongo annotations to map them to mongo collections and documents.

Suppose I have a following scenario. There are two entity classes:

- **Customer**

  ```java
  @TypeAlias("customer")
  @Document(collection = "customers")
  public class Customer implements Identifiable<String> {

      @Id
      @Size(min = 8, max = 32)
      private String id;

      @NotNull
      @Indexed
      private String name;

      // (... setters and getters are skipped)
  }
  ```
- **Claims**

  ```java
  @TypeAlias("claim")
  @Document(collection = "claims")
  public class Claims implements Identifiable<String> {

      @Id
      @Size(min = 8, max = 32)
      private String id;

      private Customer customer;

      // (... setters and getters are skipped)
  }
  ```

Consider the following scenario - operator is searching a customer (using index on name field), then creates a claim with a copy of the customer object. Customer object can be changed after claim creation, but claim data should not be affected (that's why user is copied). The actual scenario is involving larger entities.

The question is - how to prevent creation of index `customer.name` on claim collection, while reusing domain objects (without, or with minimal code duplication)?

Thanks in advance.